# SRIO interface u-boot. Cannot read IO memory

Tags: interface, io, u-boot

I try running a srio interface on my [p2020](https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/applications-processors/qoriq-platforms/p-series/qoriq-p2020-and-p2010-dual-and-single-core-communications-processors:P2020) custom board. I plug a FPGA board with srio firmware to SRIO1 and configure SRIO as a host.

In uboot_config

```
#define CONFIG_SRIO1 /* SRIO port 1 */
#define CONFIG_SYS_SRIO1_MEM_VIRT 0xC0000000
#define CONFIG_SYS_SRIO1_MEM_BUS 0xC0000000
#define CONFIG_SYS_SRIO1_MEM_PHYS CONFIG_SYS_SRIO1_MEM_BUS
#define CONFIG_SYS_SRIO1_MEM_SIZE 0x10000000 /* 256M */
```

in tlb.c

```
SET_TLB_ENTRY(1, CONFIG_SYS_SRIO1_MEM_VIRT, CONFIG_SYS_SRIO1_MEM_PHYS,
      MAS3_SX | MAS3_SW | MAS3_SR,
      MAS2_I | MAS2_G,
      0, 3, BOOKE_PAGESZ_256M, 1),
```

Try to read srio memory from u-boot

=> md.l 0xc0000000

c0000000:

p2020 is stucked.

I can watch a read request and read response on FPGA board.
Why I can't read a srio memory?

Answer (score 0):

I set a gpio 'marks' for each Interrupt vector in start.S. When I try to read Srio memory, uboot is stacked. An interrupt doesn't occur. I cannot determine the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to read the SRIO1 memory from linux

```
# devmem 0xc0000000 32  
Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Machine check in kernel mode.
Caused by (from MCSR=10008): Bus - Read Data Bus Error
Oops: Machine check, sig: 7 [#1]
SMP NR_CPUS=2 P2020 DS
Modules linked in:
CPU: 1 PID: 1578 Comm: devmem Tainted: G   M            4.9.34 #28
task: eb161a80 task.stack: ef0ca000
NIP: 1000b5fc LR: 1000b510 CTR: c02e1108
MSR: 0202d000 <VEC,CE,EE,PR,ME>  CR: 40000242  XER: 20000000
DEAR: b7e79000 ESR: 00000000 
GPR00: 40000242 bfab4250 b7e81470 b7e79000 1000b510 40000242 b7e79000 b7d88444 
GPR08: 0202d000 00000000 b7e79000 bfab4250 ef0ca000 100c8126 00000000 00000000 
GPR16: 00000000 00000000 100a3560 100c0000 100c3fc5 00000000 100c0000 00000003 
GPR24: 100c225c 100c0000 00000000 00001000 bfab4554 00000000 b7e79000 00000020 
NIP [1000b5fc] 0x1000b5fc
LR [1000b510] 0x1000b510

Oops: Machine check, sig: 7 [#1]
        arch/powerpc/kernel/traps.c +731
```

Machine check exception usually means a hardware problem. I connected the SRIO1 port to a SRIO2 of my p2020 (SRIO2 address starts at 0xd0000000)

```
# devmem 0xc0000000
0x00710002
# devmem 0xd0000000
0x00710002
```

It's work! I think, the problem in the FPGA board.